Module pyfiglet not recognized by VSCode
My VSCode doesn't recognize packages I successfully installed.
import sys
from pyfiglet import Figlet
figlet = Figlet()
fonts = figlet.getfonts()

The Line "from pyfiglet" is highlighted and doesn't work. How could I fix this?

pip list gives you feedback you really installed the package successfully?

Have you checked the Python version that the package is installed on? or your environment? If you use virtual environment such as anaconda, vs code can set anaconda environment to default.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Start by check if the dependency is really installed :
pip list | grep pyfiglet

Please, we need more informations like command line error or the error gets by your IDE.
